# Socket: sendto function changing data sent based on ip header length value

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, spoofing

I am working on packet forging and sending it through a raw socket using

```
int s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

I have a few questions. The packet I forged (and in every guide I found online) started with the iphdr. The sendto function automatically adds the ethhdr to it. Since I'm not adding it, I cant change it.
The first question was, is there any way I can manipulate the ethhdr.

Secondly, in the iphdr, my sendto acts differently based on the value of iph->ihl. If i set it to 5 (which it normally is), it changes

1. My checksum value
2. The iph->tot_len to big endian
3. The source address value in the iphdr to my computers ip if it is set to 0.0.0.0

However, with any other value it lets the packet pass smoothly without any changes.

[Here is a screenshot with iph->ihl set to 3 (not 5)[Exactly same]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkaj8.png)
[Here is a screenshot with iph->ihl set to 5 [Changed]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEXca.png)

Here are the scripts:

recv.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<errno.h>

#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>

#include<net/if.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<netinet/if_ether.h>
#include<netinet/udp.h>

#include<linux/if_packet.h>

#include<arpa/inet.h>

#define min(x,y) (x<y)?x:y

void pkt_hex_dump(uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
    int rowsize = 16;
    int i, l, linelen, remaining;
    int li = 0;
    uint8_t ch; 

    printf("\nPacket hex dump:\n");
    printf("Packet Size = %ld\n", len);

    remaining = len;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += rowsize) {
        printf("%06d\t", li);

        linelen = min(remaining, rowsize);
        remaining -= rowsize;

        for (l = 0; l < linelen; l++) {
            ch = data[l];
            printf("%02X ", (uint32_t) ch);
        }

        data += linelen;
        li += 10; 

        printf("\n");
    }
}

unsigned short csum(unsigned short *ptr,int nbytes) 
{
    register long sum;
    unsigned short oddbyte;
    register short answer;

    sum=0;
    while(nbytes>1) {
        sum+=*ptr++;
        nbytes-=2;
    }
    if(nbytes==1) {
        oddbyte=0;
        *((u_char*)&oddbyte)=*(u_char*)ptr;
        sum+=oddbyte;
    }

    sum = (sum>>16)+(sum & 0xffff);
    sum = sum + (sum>>16);
    answer=(short)~sum;
    
    return(answer);
}


int main()
{    
    int sock_r = socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (sock_r == -1) {
        printf("error in socket");
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536); 
    memset(buffer,0,65536);

    while(1)
    {
        int saddr_len, buflen;
        struct sockaddr saddr;

        saddr_len = sizeof saddr;
        buflen = recvfrom(sock_r, buffer, 65536, 0, &saddr, (socklen_t *)&saddr_len);
        printf("\n[NEW PACKET]\n");

        unsigned char* data = buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr);

        if(buflen<0)
        {
            printf("error in reading recvfrom function\n");
            return -1;
        }
        union ipv4
        {
            __be32 src;
            uint8_t ip[4];
        };
        
        struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        union ipv4 src_ip;
        src_ip.src = iph->saddr;

        struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *)(buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));

        printf("Source = %d.%d.%d.%d\n",(int)src_ip.ip[0],(int)src_ip.ip[1],(int)src_ip.ip[2],(int)src_ip.ip[3]);
        printf("Checksum Value : %d\n",(int)iph->check);
        printf("Checksum UDP : %d\n",(int)udph->check);
        printf("Data Received:\n%s\n",data);
        pkt_hex_dump((uint8_t *)iph,buflen - sizeof(struct ethhdr));

        //recheck csum values
        iph->check = 0;
        udph->source = 0;
        udph->dest = 0;
        udph->len = 0;  
        udph->check = 0;
        printf("\nRechecking Checksum:%4X\n\n",csum((unsigned short *)iph,iph->tot_len));
        
    }

    close(sock_r);
}
```

send.c

```
#include<stdio.h>   //for printf
#include<string.h> //memset
#include<sys/socket.h>  //for socket ofcourse
#include<stdlib.h> //for exit(0);
#include<errno.h> //For errno - the error number
#include<netinet/udp.h> //Provides declarations for udp header
#include<netinet/ip.h>  //Provides declarations for ip header


#define min(x,y) (x<y)?x:y

void pkt_hex_dump(uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
    int rowsize = 16;
    int i, l, linelen, remaining;
    int li = 0;
    uint8_t ch; 

    printf("\nPacket hex dump:\n");
    printf("Packet Size = %ld\n", len);

    remaining = len;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += rowsize) {
        printf("%06d\t", li);

        linelen = min(remaining, rowsize);
        remaining -= rowsize;

        for (l = 0; l < linelen; l++) {
            ch = data[l];
            printf("%02X ", (uint32_t) ch);
        }

        data += linelen;
        li += 10; 

        printf("\n");
    }
}

struct pseudo_header
{
    u_int32_t source_address;
    u_int32_t dest_address;
    u_int8_t placeholder;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t udp_length;
};

unsigned short csum(unsigned short *ptr,int nbytes) 
{
    register long sum;
    unsigned short oddbyte;
    register short answer;

    sum=0;
    while(nbytes>1) {
        sum+=*ptr++;
        nbytes-=2;
    }
    if(nbytes==1) {
        oddbyte=0;
        *((u_char*)&oddbyte)=*(u_char*)ptr;
        sum+=oddbyte;
    }

    sum = (sum>>16)+(sum & 0xffff);
    sum = sum + (sum>>16);
    answer=(short)~sum;
    
    return(answer);
}

int main (void)
{
    int s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
    
    if(s == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to create raw socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(80);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("10.0.2.15");

    char *datagram = (char*)malloc(4096);
    memset (datagram, 0, 4096);

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)datagram;
    char* data = datagram + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr);
    strcpy(data,"Hello I am here.\n");
    
    iph->ihl = 5;
    iph->version = 4;
    iph->tos = 0;
    iph->tot_len = sizeof (struct iphdr) + sizeof (struct udphdr) + strlen(data);
    iph->id = htonl (85492);    
    iph->frag_off = 0;
    iph->ttl = 255;
    iph->protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
    iph->check = 0;     //Set to 0 before calculating checksum
    //iph->saddr = inet_addr ( "1.2.3.4" ); //Spoof the source ip address
    iph->daddr = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;

    iph->check = csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->tot_len);

    struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *)(datagram + sizeof(struct iphdr));
    udph->source = htons (6666);
    udph->dest = htons (8622);
    udph->len = htons(8 + strlen(data));    
    udph->check = 0;    //leave checksum 0 now, filled later by pseudo header

    struct pseudo_header psh;
    
    psh.source_address = inet_addr( "1.2.3.4" );
    psh.dest_address = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;
    psh.placeholder = 0;
    psh.protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
    psh.udp_length = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data) );
    
    int psize = sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data);
    unsigned char *pseudogram = malloc(psize);
    
    memcpy(pseudogram , (char*) &psh , sizeof (struct pseudo_header));
    memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct pseudo_header) , udph , sizeof(struct udphdr) + strlen(data));
    
    udph->check = csum( (unsigned short*) pseudogram , psize);

    //while (1)
    {
        if (sendto (s, datagram, iph->tot_len , 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof (sin)) < 0)
        {
            perror("sendto failed");
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("Packet Send. Length : %d \n" , iph->tot_len);
            printf("Checksum Value : %d\n",(int)iph->check);
            printf("Checksum UDP : %d\n",(int)udph->check);
            pkt_hex_dump(datagram,iph->tot_len);
        }
    }
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S Can anyone can also point out why the packet is being sent twice because I only have the sendto function once in the script.

Comment: the answer to the first question is that you need raw socket to manipulate ethernet header (the same one that you use on your receiver).

Comment: the educated to the second question: that type of socket probably means that the kernel is doing IP processing (i.e., determining where to send the packet etc). If your header length is 5 (which is correct), then the kernel parses the header and does processing. if your header length is 3, then the kernel cannot parse the header. In this case i do not know why it works at all.

Comment: Thank you for clearing some of the stuff out.
I still don't know the exact parameters for initializing my required socket (I cant exactly use the one I used in the receiver as it doesn't send out packets)(I'll look around and figure that out).

Comment: Secondly if you or anyone has any light on how linux kernel calculates the checksum that would be very helpful. The way I saw was filling in the ipheader and filling in the data and then calculating the checksum. But my checksum seems to be different from the linux's calculated checksum.

Comment: does this gist help with AF_PACKET sockets: https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/1922600

Comment: it seems like IP checksum calculation is heavily optimized for each processor. This looks like a generic versionhttps://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/checksum.c#L106. The do_csum function is on line 46 of the same file, scroll up.

Comment: Thank you so much. The AF_PACKET socket sends raw packets with ethhdr (although I have to change the address structure used for sendto function). And I'll look more into the checksum value but now I have a sense of direction. You've really helped out alot.